# CheckBox Label color change on button submitting

Tags: checkbox, colors, label

First step in HTML

I would like to change color of checkbox labels after pressing validation button : green if ok, red if wrong selection.

Here is my code :
'
50
100
500
1000

```
    <button onclick="verif();">VERIFIER</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>'
```

function verif()
{
if(choix1.checked)
{
document.getElementById('50').style.color = 'red';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button id="verifybutton" onclick="verif();">VERIFIER</button>
//js code        
function verif() { if(choix1.checked) { 
document.getElementById('verifybutton').style.color = 'red'; }
```

you can try like this